# Vue JS3 route transition start activity with left to right mode

Tags: vuejs3

I'm new here and I'm new to Vue JS, but I couldn't do what I wanted to do. As can be seen from the image below, I want to perform transition operations, but I could not achieve what I wanted. exactly what I want; I want to do what I want to do in the "url" I have specified with meta and css. I may have answered the question incorrectly and I want to apologize to all of you in advance.

For example; I'm on the home page and when transitioning to the "menu-home'" page, the transition should be like this: It will open from left to right and with a z-index value of 101. When "home" is requested from the "menu-home" page, "menu-home" should be closed to the left. And the "home" page will open from right to left.

Activity1
Activity2
Activity3

[text](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav#using-navlink)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f8QL.png)

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
  <transition
    :enter-active-class="route.meta.enterClass"
    :leave-active-class="route.meta.leaveClass"
  >
    <component :is="Component" />
  </transition>
</router-view>


{
  path: '/home',
  name: 'home',
  component: () => import('../pages/Home.vue'),
  meta: {
    enterClass: '',
    leaveClass: '',
  },
},
{
  path: '/menu-home',
  name: 'menu-home',
  component: () => import('../pages/MenuHome.vue'),
  meta: {
    enterClass: '',
    leaveClass: '',
  },
},
```

I couldn't write the necessary CSS

transition css how to